# ¿Como puedo imprimir una lista de objetos (objetos de clase) en Python?

Tags: python, poo, lista

he creado una lista de objetos a raíz de una clase (lista de objetos)

```
while count < numTotalPC:
    ip = DHCPServer.getipDisponibles()[0]
    pc = PC("pc" + str(count), ip, network, gateway)
    switch.anadirPCs(pc)  # <- es la funcion set de la lista
```

y lo imprimo de la siguiente manera:

```
print("Lista de ordenadores:")

print(switch.getPCs())  # <- funcion get de la lista PC's
```

como podria imprimir los objetos con sus atributos y que no salga de la siguiente manera?

PC.PC object at 0x0000000002A5B948, PC.PC object at 0x0000000002A5B888

Comment: Si defines un método llamado `__repr__()` en tu clase, que devuelva una cadena, esa será la que se mostrará al imprimir el objeto. Puedes confeccionar una cadena juntando los datos que quieras hacer visibles, que pueden ser atributos del objeto, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba si te sirve de esta forma:

Utilizando lo siguiente en tu clase `PC`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.__dict__)
```

Y ésta es la prueba que hice:

```
class PC():

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2, attr3):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2
        self.attr3 = attr3

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

arr = []
arr.append(PC('a', 'b', 'c'))
arr.append(PC('d', 'e', 'f'))
arr.append(PC('g', 'h', 'i'))
arr.append(PC('j', 'k', 'l'))
print(arr)
```

Obteniendo como resultado:

> [{'attr1': 'a', 'attr2': 'b', 'attr3': 'c'}, {'attr1': 'd', 'attr2': 'e', 'attr3': 'f'}, {'attr1': 'g', 'attr2': 'h', 'attr3': 'i'}, {'attr1': 'j', 'attr2': 'k', 'attr3': 'l'}]

Para más información de `__repr__` puedes revisar [éste link](https://jarroba.com/repr-y-str-de-python/)

No repliqué al 100% tu código pero imagino que estas utilizando algo similar.

Espero te sirva ;)

Comment: al final utilice un __str__ para devolver  los valores de los atributos, gracias por tu respuesta!